# When try to concatenate URL with variable it do not give expected result in php curl

Tags: php, curl

I try to read XML document and convert content in to JSON using curl in php.
In here i want to concatenate URL with variable.

but when add variable it retrieve null. but when i hard code text it works.

this is my code.

```
       $city = "paris";
       $url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22{$city}%22)";
        print_r($url);
       // $url ="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

        $data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
        curl_close($ch);

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
        echo json_encode($xml);
```

this is my url

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22{$city}%22)
```

It works when i add "paris" rather than {$city}

please help me to sortout this problem.

Comment: If i print the url i got your URL correctly like `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22paris%22)`

Comment: @Nawin worked for me too

Comment: `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22paris%22)`, it's working fine.

Comment: yes it prints correct URl. But it do not give result as i expected. json object retrive "false"

Comment: i found the issue. string variable contais new line at last. because of that it affect to the URL. URL it devided to two part. i use this for it. $city = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $_REQUEST['city']));

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the url and concatenate and encode the url like :

```
$city = "paris";
$url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22{$city}%22)";
$url1 = urldecode($url);
print_r(urlencode($url1));
```

By the way i test your code in my localhost it shows me correct output screen shot is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In here there is another problem. URL concatenate correctly with variable.

But the thing is i take value to variable via POST method. when send test via POST method it contains new line at last. becouse of that when i add variable to urs it devided to 2 parts.

I solved it by "trim" method.

```
$city = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $_REQUEST['city']));
```

When use like that it worked.